# How to get the request original parameters before the .net convertion / binding?

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I have a model which looks like this:

```
public class SignalModelEntity
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public BooleanValue ValueBoolean { get; set; }
}
```

and a ValueBoolean class:

```
public class BooleanValue 
{
    public bool? Value { get; set; }
    public string FormattedValue { get; set; }
}
```

When sending a body with a json that looks like this:

```
...
"ValueBoolean": {
    "Value": 23,
    "FormattedValue": ""
}
```

Lets say the user sent me a '23' as a value.

The binding/convertion gives me a value of "true" for the boolean value property inside the ValueBoolean class.

I want to recognize rather the user sent me a '1', 'true' so I can approve that the value is legal and true.

And if the user for example sent me a '23' so it's illegal and return a 'badRequest' error code.

So how can I get the original parameters that sent from the request?

My post method is as follows:

```
[Route("{patientId}")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(int patientId, [FromBody]SignalModelEntity signal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your method definition as follows:

```
    [Route("{patientId}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int patientId, [FromBody]dynamic signal)
```

You can access the original value as follows:

```
var originalValue = signal.Value.Value;
```

You'll probably need to create your custom JsonConverter for converting this dynamic signal to SignalModelEntity object.

Comment: The requested development is to use POST with query paramters ;)